# Alfresco Activiti BPM dynamically get candidate groups or users

Tags: java, activiti

Is it possible to define `candidateGroups` or `candidateUsers` dynamically in Activiti?
I would like to do something like this:

`<userTask id="approve" name="approve" activiti:candidateUsers="${myWorkflowService.getCandidateUsers()}"></userTask>`

and then in a Java class, `MyWorkflowService`, I would define the method `getCandidateUsers()` to return the list of users/groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve is like this:

I added an `executionListener` to a transition before that userTasK:

`<activiti:executionListener event="start" expression="${myWorkflowService.getCandidateUsers(execution)}"></activiti:executionListener>`

And in my class I define this method:

`public void getCandidateUsers(DelegateExecution execution) {
    execution.setVariable("approver", "foo");
}`

Comment: Since this is a user task, you actually have an event explicitly created for this purpose. It is the assign event (which triggers before create) on user tasks. Not to say your option doesnt work, just thought I'd let you know there is an event available for this very purpose.